# How can i load next audio song while one is playing in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, html5-audio

I have made a custom audio player in JavaScript its plays fine all the audio tracks however I am having an issue when it loads next MP3 file.  It takes long time to load. Now is that possible in JavaSript if we can load (buffer) the next MP3 file while the player is playing one so the listener would get delay and songs are playing smoothly?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: yes, it's possible. Javascript is good at doing things asynchronously. But I'd need to see your code to know how to help you with it. Can you give a minimal example of the way your code looks?

Comment: Yes sure you can i ll post the code so you can view and help me thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to buffer the next track is to create a second audio object.

```
const audio1 = new Audio('first.mp3');
audio1.play();

const audio2 = new Audio('second.mp3');
```

When you set the URL for the audio element, it will buffer some data ahead of time.

If you want to force loading the entire thing, I suggest using ServiceWorkers to intercept the request from the audio object, drop the `Range` request header, and cache the entire response.

Comment: Thanks i ll try it tomorrow and i ll update you if its works thanks again